# How to select DISTINCT records from the database in Grafana

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I'm using Grafana and I want to select DISTINCT records from the database. How can I do that?

[image]

The query is:

```
SELECT reference AS "Reference", reference_url AS "Reference URL" FROM daily_run_vehicle WHERE retries >= 5 GROUP BY reference, reference_url ORDER BY 1;
```

But when I try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (reference) AS "Reference", reference_url AS "References" FROM daily_run_vehicle WHERE retries >= 5 GROUP BY reference, reference_url ORDER BY 1;
```

I get the same result.

The `data source` that I use in Grafana is `Postgres`.

**UPDATE**

The result that I get is as follows:

[image]

You see that third and fourth records have the same first column (reference). I do not want that, I want to show only one.

Thus it should be:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function it always applies to all columns in the select list. `distinct (a),b,c` is the same as `distinct a,b,(c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting 4 results because `SELECT DISTINCT` returns rows where the values are distinct across ALL selected fields. So because the combination of `reference` and `reference_url` are different in rows 3 and 4, they are still both returned in a `DISTINCT`.

To do a `DISTINCT` on only a subset of the fields being returned, use `DISTINCT ON` to tell it which fields to use for checking uniqueness, followed by a list of fields to return:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (reference) reference, reference_url
FROM daily_run_vehicle
WHERE retries >= 5
ORDER BY reference
```

I've removed the `GROUP BY` as `DISTINCT ON` with an order is the same as a `GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1`; however if you really do want to group by both fields then you need a `DISTINCT ON (reference, reference_url)`, in which case you actually want 4 records returned.